# Delete text after second hyphen

Tags: excel, text, vba

I want delete text and hyphen to the right, in Excel.

My column example:

```
Fresh Start Recovery, Inc. - Wayne
FSA Property Mgmt - Danny
Georgia Securing Svcs, Inc. - Katrina
Georgia - SFFS - Joe & Roxana
Greenwood - Lonnie
Griffis Recovery, LLC - Tyler (5% WC)
Hi Cap, Inc. - Doug
```

I need the it to look like this:

```
Fresh Start Recovery, Inc.
FSA Property Mgmt
Georgia Securing Svcs, Inc.
Georgia - SFFS
Greenwood
Griffis Recovery, LLC
Hi Cap, Inc.
```

I have code that will delete the text and hyphen to the right, but if I have two hyphens I need it to delete the second one, my code deletes the first one.

```
Dim iPos As String
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Range("a1:a" & Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
iPos = InStr(1, c.Value, " - ")
If iPos > 0 Then
c.Value = Left(c.Value, iPos - 1)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InStrRev` finds the last string match by looking backwards.

This updated code

- uses variant arrays for speed rather than range loops
- tests for a " -" then uses `InStrRev` to find the position of the last occurrence
- uses the string function `Left$` rather than the variant `Left`

  ```
  Sub Test()
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim X
  Dim lngrow As Long
  Set rng1 = Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
  X = rng1.Value2
  For lngrow = 1 To UBound(X)
  If InStr(X(lngrow, 1), " -") Then X(lngrow, 1) = Left$(X(lngrow, 1), InStrRev(X(lngrow, 1), " -", , vbBinaryCompare) - 1)
  Next
  rng1.Value2 = X
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: That worked perfect! Thanks so much, I been working on this for days.

Answer (score 0):

Using InStrRev instead of InStr